# TinyMCE remove "format" drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How do I remove the "format" drop down button?

I tried `theme_advanced_blockformats : 'h2,h3,p'`, but doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#description",
    menubar: false,
    theme_advanced_blockformats : 'h2,h3,p',
    toolbar: " undo redo | removeformat | styleselect | bold italic | link | print preview media fullpage", 
    plugins: [
         "link"
        ],
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of :

```
toolbar: " undo redo | removeformat | styleselect | bold italic | link | print preview media fullpage",
```

try (without `styleselect`):

```
toolbar: " undo redo | removeformat | bold italic | link | print preview media fullpage",
```